# Почему forEach работает не правильно?

Tags: javascript

По идее код должен вырезать из массива все значения, кроме цифр, но происходит вообще непонятно что, возможно я как-то не так применил функцию `ForEach`;

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  l.forEach(onlyNumber)

  function onlyNumber(item, i, arr) {
    if(typeof item !== Number) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  
  return l;

}

console.log(filter_list(['a', 1, 3, 'b']));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методом `.splice()` вы меняете сам массив во время работы `.forEach()`. Используйте `.filter()`, если вам нужно профильтровать массив

```
function filterList(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function (item) {
    return typeof item === 'number';
  });
}

console.log(filterList(['a', 1, 3, 'b']));
```

2. Оператор `typeof` возвращает строку